# Install a renewed SSL certificate in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, keystore

I successfully installed a GoDaddy SSL certificate in Tomcat last year.

When the certificate expired, I renewed it. I did this without generating a new keystore or CSR. GoDaddy delivered three files to me, gd_bundle.crt, gd_intermediate.crt, and a third .crt file with a random number as the name.

I don't know what to do next. I assume I have to incorporate these files into my existing keystore. GoDaddy provides this help page:
http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/5355/ssl-certificate-renewal-tomcat-4-x5-x6-x

The page says I can do this one of two ways. I tried the first way and all I got was an error message saying "-inkey: no such file or directory". I tried the second way, but I do not have any file with the name it references, and also any attempt to import the new certs into the existing keystore results in an error "certificate not imported, alias already exists".

What is the correct way to update my keystore file with the new certificate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the keytool to import the numbered file into the existing KeyStore, using the same alias you're already using, with the -importcert option.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I didn't know about the -importcert command. I was trying to delete the old ones and -import the new ones, which seemed to work, but produced an invalid certificate.

Comment: You need the old alias because it contains the keypair. Without that, you got nothing.

Comment: Hello i have same problem. i got 3 files after renew certificate. what to do next? i found tutorial as Frank mentioned in question. i have old keystore, how can i import new certificate provide by godaddy? please help

Comment: same problem, even when I follow your direction to use importcert.  In fact, my situation is exactly the same, with the 3 files.  In my case, I get "root" alias already exists.

Comment: facing issue. error -> java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match